Computing $L^2$ norm and quadrature for time-varying solution to PDE?
Setup. On domain $\Omega \times (0,T]$, the parabolic problem
\begin{align}
u_t + \Delta u + u = f
\end{align}
with some appropriate initial and boundary conditions has solution $u(x,t)$, which I approximate as $u_h(x,t)$ using the Galerkin finite element method. Let's say I discretize in space using piecewise linear elements with diameter at most $h$ and I discretize in time using backward Euler with timestep $\tau$. Then theory predicts order $O(h^2 + \tau)$ rate of convergence in the $L^2$ norm.
Questions. (1) For time-varying functions, how do I both correctly notate and compute the $L^2$ norm? (2) More importantly, what is the appropriate way to approximate the $L^2$ norm using quadrature?
My Guess. My guess for (1) is that $\| v \|_{L^2([0,T];\Omega)} = (\int_0^T \int_\Omega |v|^2 dx dt)^{1/2}$. For (2), I know how to take quadrature over the spatial domain at a given time step; let's say that $Q(|v(t)|^2) \approx \|v(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2$. Do I just do $(\sum_{j=1}^n Q(|v(j\tau)|^2) \cdot \tau)^{1/2}$ where $n$ is s.t. $n\tau = T$? i.e. do I just take quadrature at each time step, multiply by the time step size, and add?
Now what if I discretize in time with a higher order method that converges like $O(h^2 + \tau^2)$...does that change the answer to (2)?

I would suppose one should compute : $\int u'{ij}u'{kl}a_{ij}=\int \dot{u}{ij}u{kl}a_{ij}$. This means the matrix of coefficients is in the kernel of the difference tensor, supposing f=0. It is easily applicable for non null f and adding u. But the problem arrives at the diagonalisation of an order 4 tensor, which i suppose could be solved with rearranging in matrix form.

This would mean there exist several evolutions, hence worse than quantum
